# Как добавить 360 фотографию на сайт

Tags: javascript, html

мне необходимо добавить фотографию VR на сайт. Как это реализовать?

Опыта в этом деле нету, я находил информацию о том что можно воспользоваться Three.js или Babylon, но не смог разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Для фреймворка Babylon.js ответ можно найти в [Официальной справке](https://doc.babylonjs.com/divingDeeper/environment/360PhotoDome)

Простейший пример:

```
var createScene = function () {
var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", -Math.PI / 2,  Math.PI / 2, 5, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);
camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
camera.inputs.attached.mousewheel.detachControl(canvas);

var dome = new BABYLON.PhotoDome(
    "testdome",
    "./textures/360photo.jpg",
    {
        resolution: 32,
        size: 1000
    },
    scene
);

return scene;};
```

Comment: Спасибо за правку ответа! Голос на удаление я уже дал, его невозможно отозвать обратно. Если вдруг ответ будет удалён автоматиикой (что маловероятно), просто нажмите кнопку  "Востановление".